# How can i change mobile menu one scroll to multiple pages?

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have one page scroll menu,but i've changed that in multiple page.These kind of menu is working on desktop,but is not working on mobile version.How can I change code css or html because in mobile version when i click on menu and close it anywhere i clicked redirectg me to another page.

```css
.mobile-menu {
 display: block;
     width: 18%;
    right: -20%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(1, 16, 25, 0.67);
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9998;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}

.mobile-menu ul {
 position: relative;
    top: 20%;
    padding: 0;
}

.mobile-menu ul li { 
 list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
 display: block;
}
.mobile-menu ul li a {
 width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    padding: 1em 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}
.open > ul.dropdown-menu.agile_short_dropdown{
    display: block;
    transform: none !important;
    min-width: 65%;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    left: 18%;
}
.open > ul.dropdown-menu.agile_short_dropdown li{
 margin:0 !important;
}
ul.dropdown-menu.agile_short_dropdown > li > a:hover{
    background: none;
}
.mobile-menu ul li a:after {
 content: '';
    background: #191143;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 right: -100%;
 top: 0;
 z-index: -1;
 transition: 0.4s ease;
}

.mobile-menu ul li a:hover,.mobile-menu ul li.active a { 
 color: #fff; 
}

.mobile-menu ul li a:hover:after,.mobile-menu ul li.active a:after { 
 right: 0; 
}
li.dropdown.act a.w3_icons_act {
    background: #0e0e0e;
 color: #fff;
}
.mobile-menu img {
 position: absolute;
 width: 150px;
 display: block;
 left: 50%;
 top: 3rem;
 transform: translatex(-50%);
 -webkit-transform: translatex(-50%);
 -moz-transform: translatex(-50%);
 -o-transform: translatex(-50%);
 -ms-transform: translatex(-50%);
 padding: 0;
 text-align: center;
}

.mobile-menu--open {
 opacity: 1;
 right:0%;
}
.dropdown.active.open a  ul.dropdown-menu.agile_short_dropdown li a.w3_icon_1:after{
 background:none !important;
```

```html
  <div class="center-container">
   <div class="w3_agile_header">
       <div class="w3_menu">
       <div class="agileits_w3layouts_banner_info">
    
       </div>
        <div class="mobile-nav-button">
         <div class="mobile-nav-button__line"></div>
         <div class="mobile-nav-button__line"></div>
         <div class="mobile-nav-button__line"></div>
        </div>
        <nav class="mobile-menu">
         <ul>
          <li><a href="https://ioanasandu.ro/online/web/index.html" class="hover" >Despre mine</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://ioanasandu.ro/online/web/repertoriu.html" class="scroll">Repertoriu</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://ioanasandu.ro/online/web/discografie.html" class="scroll">Discografie</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://ioanasandu.ro/online/web/evenimente.html" class="scroll">Evenimente</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://ioanasandu.ro/online/web/foto.html" class="scroll">Foto</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://ioanasandu.ro/online/web/video.html" class="scroll">Video</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://ioanasandu.ro/online/web/contact.html" class="scroll">Contact</a></li>
         </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
     <div class="clearfix"></div>
       </div>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you share live link ?

Comment: ioanasandu.ro/online/web/contact.html

Comment: I've changed class="click" to all pages.In mobile version after i close menu,anything i click comand to another page on the right part where is menu mobile background

Comment: can you verify on mobile this web adress and look mobile menu and push on the right side anywhere for you can understand what is the problem.I hope you can help me!

Comment: Instead of class, use id reference, https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_scrollspy.asp (I believe you using bootstrap )

Comment: Yes i use bootstrap.I must delete class from html? What id reference i use and where i put the code?Can you  send me a code for bootstrap or html?

Comment: follow these tow http://prntscr.com/roxp7x http://prntscr.com/roxp4u

Comment: yes,thanks,but i want to not click after i close menu.Do you test my page on mobile device?

Comment: ok got it, I don't have the solution, wait for any other community user if they have any solution.

Comment: Thank you very much.Perhaps you know how to put body scroll when menu mobile is open